# Error while building Apache Mahout 0.11.0

Tags: maven, mahout

I tried to build Mahout 0.11 [from the source](https://github.com/apache/mahout/tree/mahout-0.11.0) by

```
mvn install/mvn -DskipTests install -e
```

and received the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.501s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 28 17:11:17 AST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-versions) on project mahout-buildtools: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-versions) on project mahout-buildtools: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute(EnforceMojo.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

Found this link, while trying to troubleshoot: https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/3262/changes

Just want to know if there is a work around (making changes in pom file)

Update: Upon running with maven 3.3.3 and Java 1.7, I am able to build Mahout 0.11

Comment: You missed the important part of the log (just above "BUILD FAILURE") where Maven tells you the rules that have been broken. You need to compile using Maven 3.3.3 with JDK 7.

Comment: @Tunaki: Thank you for responding. That part of log was "warning"; anyways, I will try with JDK 7 and maven 3.3.3. Did you have any success with it?

Comment: Update: Upon running with maven 3.3.3 and Java 1.7, I am able to build Mahout 0.11

Comment: Don't add [SOLVE] to the title.